# Best way to send and receive image files in JSON in webservice?

Tags: java, json, web-services, base64, bson

Please suggest the best way to send and receive image files using JSON?

Comment: base64 encoding? [java sending binary data json](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+sending+binary+data+json&oq=java+sending+binary+data+json&aqs=chrome..69i57.10643j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Android: Upload image or file using `http` POST `multi-part`

By using multi-part ,  you will be able to upload a file from your SD Card and also Bitmap image as a file.

Prerequisite: httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar

Android SDK uses apache  http Client of version 3.0. That does not support for the mime type.

```
package com.isummation.fileupload;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class FileUpload extends Activity {
    Bitmap bm;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            // bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            // R.drawable.forest);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/DCIM/forest.png");
            executeMultipartPost();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void executeMultipartPost() throws Exception {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://10.0.2.2/cfc/iphoneWebservice.cfc?returnformat=json&amp;method=testUpload");
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "forest.jpg");
            // File file= new File("/mnt/sdcard/forest.png");
            // FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("uploaded", bab);
            reqEntity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody("sfsdfsdf"));
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
            System.out.println("Response: " + s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception here
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

See below link:

[Multipart Image Upload](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)